# Building a binary executable for a MacOS app, on Linux

Tags: macos, executable, binaryfiles, .app

I have at the core a very simple program.  A shell script that can run on either mac or ubuntu.  I have the requirement to distribute it on both platforms (in the mac case, must be a .app), however, I must build it exclusively on Ubuntu.

I was looking in to what is a mac '.app', and it seems like it's just a unique  directory structure with executable, metadata, etc.  For example, here are Apple's docs on the matter which explains it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

It seems like the metadata, etc. can all be put together, however in the Contents/MacOS folder, this is where the executable (the app's entrypoint) goes.  This is the part I am confused on.  For example, is there a way to make my shell script as an 'executable'?  Or does this need to be a proper binary file (like you would get by compiling a C program?).  If it is the latter, is there a way to do this on a Linux machine?  (Noting that, this shell script, or C script I could make it in to, is so simple - essentially a single if/else statement which calls another utility.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two things:

1. Put your executable into the `Contents/MacOS` directory, and make sure it is world-executable (just call `chmod 755` on it). I think a shell script should work here, as long as it's got the correct "shebang" in front. For an actual binary, you'd need to find a way to compile a Mach-O binary on Linux.
2. Next, you need to make an `Info.plist` file in the `Contents` directory. Just dig out any Apple plist file as a template, and put these keys in it:

   a. `CFBundleExecutable`—this should be the filename of your executable in `Contents/MacOS`

   b. `CFBundleIdentifier`—this should be a unique bundle ID for your application, in reverse-DNS notation, i.e. `com.yourwebsitename.yourappname`

If you have these components in your .app bundle, it should launch when you double-click on it.